# Return sum of values in the map with conditions

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm doing a Java practice which ask me to return the sum of the values in the map where the corresponding key string has a length less than or equal to maxLength.

[image]

I totally have no idea how the map works.

```
import java.util.Map;

public class MapSum {
    public static int mapSum(Map<String, Integer> map, int maxLength) {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet();
    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far. I plan to turn the map into a set for easier comparison of the length, but it have error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a set to do this.  All it involves is a simple loop.

First, initialize sum to 0;

```
int sum = 0;
```

Then start with a for loop.

```
for(Entry<String,Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
```

to get the string use `e.getKey()` and check its length. If it is within the range of the supplied length, then add the value to sum, otherwise, do nothing but proceed to the next value.

```
sum += e.getValue();
```

Once done summing the values, then

```
return sum;
```

Comment: Do I need to import extra library for `Entry<String,Integer> e : map.entrySet()` cause I got error on this statement. I imported `import java.util.Map;` already

Comment: Yes.  I failed to mention that.  It is an interface that is defined in the Map interface.

Comment: I got it, should be `for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {`

Comment: That'll work.  Usually you don't need the Map prefix.